# Getting PHP errors to log in Nginx/PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, logging, logs

Under Nginx/PHP-FPM, I can't get PHP errors logged to `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` as they should be.

Initially, errors weren't logging *anywhere*, but I discovered I needed:
`catch_workers_output = yes` in our PHP-FPM config.

Errors are now logging to `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log`, but not to Craft's custom location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only 80% confident in this answer, but I'm pretty sure that runtime PHP [`ini_set`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) calls won't work with nginx running with FastCGI (which is what Craft uses to change the [error_log](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) path.

Try setting that path directly in your `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` file.

Comment: After much fussing, figured this out.

Comment: ↑ Seemingly, any value for `error_log` (or maybe anything?) in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf` will override even what is set in your pool conf. (e.g. `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/mysite.conf`), `.user.ini`, and of course runtime `ini_set`. What I did was comment out the `error_log` line in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf` and added php_value[error_log] = ... to Craft's storage path in my pool config.

Seems backward...what is especially confusing is looking at phpinfo, the values appear to be overriding, but wont actually work!

Comment: Computers... AMIRITE?!

Comment: They're the worst. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻